# Android: BaseAdapter not showing elements

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

The app I'm struggling to make has a simple list and a button present in the bottom no matter what. My problem is that my custom BaseAdapter doesn't show elements. I know that since my elements are only a string I could use an ArrayAdapter, but the assignment requires it. The code:

```
class ListaOrase extends BaseAdapter{
    private Activity context;
    ArrayList<String> orase;

    public ListaOrase(Activity context){
        this.context=context;
        orase=new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    public void add(String string){
        orase.add(string);
    }
public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup list)  {
        View element;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
         LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
         element = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista, null);
        }
        else element = convertView;
        TextView elementLista=(TextView)element.findViewById(R.id.elementLista);    
        elementLista.setText(orase.get(position));
        return element;
    }

}
public class WeatherAppActivity extends ListActivity {

    Button buton;
    ListaOrase lista;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lista=new ListaOrase(this);
        buton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buton);
        setListAdapter(lista);

        lista.add("Bucuresti");
        lista.add("Sibiu");

    }
}
```

My XML files go like this:

```
main.xml -- for the Activity
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >



<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<Button
        android:id="@+id/buton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="add"
        android:text="Add"
        android:layout_gravity=""
        /> 
        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
lista.xml -- for the list
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/elementLista"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

The button "downstairs" opens a dialog that adds items to my list. It obviously doesn't work, but I think it's the BaseAdapter (ListaOrase) itself, as the intents throw no exceptions. I would be thankful if the items I hardcoded in would show up (Bucuresti and Sibiu).

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you very much! :)

Comment: did you override all the baseadapter methods in ListaOrase class?

Comment: Yes, but I've cut them from the code here to save space and look cleaner. The code compiles, has no syntax errors and throws no exceptions.

Comment: hey setListAdapter(lista); after list.add() statements and try, get me the result

Comment: try to print orase.get(position) in getview method(In log)

Comment: It's not showing anything, so I can only conclude that getView() doesn't get called. Ideas? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code almost perfect issue is return orase.size() in getcount() method,you are returning 0, add unimplemented methods in ListaOrase class.
your ListaOrase  should be like this:

```
class ListaOrase extends BaseAdapter{
    private Activity context;
    ArrayList<String> orase;

    public ListaOrase(Activity context){
        this.context=context;
        orase=new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    public void add(String string){
        orase.add(string);
    }

    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup list)  {
        View element;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
         LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
         element = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista, null);
        }
        else element = convertView;
        TextView elementLista=(TextView)element.findViewById(R.id.elementLista);    
        elementLista.setText(orase.get(position));
        Log.e("",orase.get(position));
        return element;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return orase.size();
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Like I've said, I already have them implemented, I only omitted them from here in order to save space. I'll add them so you can get the full picture, but that's not it. From what I can tell, the getView() method doesn't get called.

Comment: worked for me, i tested your code,in getcount method return orase.size(), you are returning 0, see my code above

Comment: Now it works perfectly. I can't see the differences in our two codes though. What did you change exactly because it's totally bugging me! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`getCount` method was really returning 0 so consquently `getView()` wasn't being called. When I changed to:

```
getcount() {  
    return arrayObject.Size();
}
```