# ListView using Custom Adapter not displaying anything

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am have SQLite DB and I am trying to display queried values in a listView.
I followed [this](http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.com/2013/02/android-list-view-using-custom-adapter.html) tutorial to create a custom adapter for the listView. Also used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368373/android-baseadapter-not-showing-elements) question as reference.

---

I am not able to see any data displayed on my listView.

The custom listView row should have 3 items - Description, Date & Amount(view defined in [this](https://gist.github.com/bharatkrishna/5175158) xml). Values for these are fetched from the db. The fetch from db looks fine.

My Custom Adapter code:

```
public class TransactionListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<TransactionItem> transactionList; 
    // Code for TransactionItem class : https://gist.github.com/bharatkrishna/5175105

    public TransactionListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TransactionItem> list) {

        this.context = context;
        transactionList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return transactionList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return transactionList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("adpater", "I am in adapter"); // Doesn't seem to get to this point as I don't see the log message
        View element;
        TransactionItem transactionItem = transactionList.get(position);        
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            element = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_entry, null);

         } else {
             element = convertView;
         }
        // Code of XML file with these widgets defined: https://gist.github.com/bharatkrishna/5175158
        TextView descTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descText_Report);
        descTextView.setText(transactionItem.getDescription());

        TextView dateTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateText_Report);
        dateTextView.setText(transactionItem.getDate());

        TextView amountTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amountText_Report);
        amountTextView.setText(Float.toString(transactionItem.getAmount()));        

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

I'm using this adapter in my activity as follows:

```
public class ReportsActivity extends Activity {
ListView listView;  
private DatabaseHelper db;
private Cursor transactions;
...
...
private void showList() {
    ArrayList<TransactionItem> transactionList = new ArrayList<TransactionItem>();
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);          
    transactions = db.getTransaction();

    // This successfully dumps the db contents to log output. Querying from DB seems to be working fine.    
    Log.d("db", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(transactions)); 

        if (transactions != null && transactions.getCount() != 0) {
            do {
                TransactionItem transactionItem = new TransactionItem();

                transactionItem.setDescription(transactions.getString(transactions.getColumnIndex("description")));

                transactionItem.setDate(transactions.getString(transactions.getColumnIndex("date")));

                transactionItem.setAmount(transactions.getFloat(transactions.getColumnIndex("amount")));
            } while (transactions.moveToNext());
    }           
        TransactionListAdapter transactionListAdapter = new TransactionListAdapter(ReportsActivity.this, transactionList);
        listView.setAdapter(transactionListAdapter); //listView is defined in onCreate() method
  }
}
```

Where am I going wrong.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**: Changed the code for TransactionListAdapter's getView() method, getting rid of else case. I was changing code & pasted a buggy code here. This was spotted by @James Baca. I now have :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TransactionItem transactionListItems = transactionList.get(position);
    Log.d("adpater", "I am in adapter");
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_entry, null);

    }       

    TextView descTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descText_Report);
    descTextView.setText(transactionListItems.getDescription());

    TextView dateTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateText_Report);
    dateTextView.setText(transactionListItems.getDate());

    TextView amountTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amountText_Report);
    amountTextView.setText(Float.toString(transactionListItems.getAmount()));       

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: have you checked if the TransactionItem has data?

Comment: I had put in a Log in there & I could see it reach setDescription & print the value of descriotion but does not get to getDescription. Here's my code of TransactionItem: https://gist.github.com/bharatkrishna/5175105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**You haven't set the transaction object to the list**, so your list is empty

Add this

```
transactionList.add(transactionItem);
```

in your while loop of `showList()` method

Answer (score 2):

I think u should  replace  convertview to element ..like this

```
     TextView descTextView = (TextView) element.findViewById(R.id.descText_Report);
    descTextView.setText(transactionItem.getDescription());

    TextView dateTextView = (TextView) element.findViewById(R.id.dateText_Report);
    dateTextView.setText(transactionItem.getDate());

    TextView amountTextView = (TextView) element.findViewById(R.id.amountText_Report);
    amountTextView.setText(Float.toString(transactionItem.getAmount())); 

    return element;
```

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was fiddling around changing code. I now totally got rid of element and that else condition and am using only the contextView. The bug was as mentioned by Pragnani.
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug with convertView.findViewById() when convertView is null this can and will fail.  This will happen when the adapter is first used and there is no convertView initially being passed in.

I recommend:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d("adpater", "I am in adapter"); // Doesn't seem to get to this point as I don't see the log message

    TransactionItem transactionItem = transactionList.get(position);        
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_entry, null);

     } 
    // Code of XML file with these widgets defined: https://gist.github.com/bharatkrishna/5175158
    TextView descTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descText_Report);
    descTextView.setText(transactionItem.getDescription());

    TextView dateTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateText_Report);
    dateTextView.setText(transactionItem.getDate());

    TextView amountTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amountText_Report);
    amountTextView.setText(Float.toString(transactionItem.getAmount()));        

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized this and changed it now. This was a bug but the real bug was the one found by @Pragnani. Fixed it now.